# How to set Min and Max date for Google timeline charts?

Tags: google-visualization

I would like to set the Min and Max date in Google timeline charts.
[Google Timeline Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline)

I have tried using

```
 hAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
          min: new Date(2014, 1, 31)
        }}
```

and

```
 hAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
          minValue: new Date(2014, 1, 31)
        }}
```

both does not work. If there is no way to set the date ranges, how to get the Min and Max date values that is set by the api itself?

Comment: Options for controlling the axes of the Timeline chart are not yet available.

Answer (score 14):

[Google Charts version 43](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes?hl=en#october-2-2015) (released October 2, 2015) supports minValue and maxValue for the horizontal axis:

```
....

var options = {
  hAxis: {
    minValue: new Date(1785, 0, 0),
    maxValue: new Date(1816, 0, 0)
  }
};

....
```

You have to load it via the [frozen version loader](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/library_loading_enhancements#frozen-versions) though since apparently it [wasn't successfully deployed by the usual process](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-visualization-api/6Gexd2lr8vU/fj32KG08BwAJ).

It looks like minValue and maxValue works only for putting spacing at the beginning and end of the timeline.  So if you specify a minValue that is later than the start date of one of your data points, the timeline still starts at that data point and not at the minValue.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o27ttyy3) that shows minValue and maxValue providing spacing at the beginning and end of the first Google Timeline example: https://jsfiddle.net/o27ttyy3

Comment: It works but apparently it still takes the maxValue from the chart if the maxValue in the code is below it. That sucks.