# How to set X axis range with dates on X-axis in google timeline range chart as well as make X axis scrollable

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I want to set minimum and maximum date(range) on X-axis in google range bar chart but not able to set it using below code:

```
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['timeline']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Activity', 'Start Time', 'End Time'],
    ['Sleep',
     new Date(2014, 10, 15, 0, 30),
     new Date(2014, 10, 15, 6, 30)],
    ['Eat Breakfast',
     new Date(2014, 10, 17, 6, 45),
     new Date(2014, 10, 18, 7)],
    ['Get Ready',
     new Date(2014, 10, 19, 7, 4),
     new Date(2014, 10, 22, 7, 30)],
    ['Commute To Work',
     new Date(2014, 10, 22, 7, 30),
     new Date(2014, 10, 24, 8, 30)],
    ['Work',
     new Date(2014, 10, 24, 8, 30),
     new Date(2014, 10, 25, 17)],
    ['Commute Home',
     new Date(2014, 10,  25, 17),
     new Date(2014, 10,  26, 18)],
    ['Gym',
     new Date(2014, 10, 26, 18),
     new Date(2014, 10,  27, 18, 45)],
    ['Eat Dinner',
     new Date(2014, 10,  27, 19),
     new Date(2014, 10,  28, 20)],
    ['Get Ready For Bed',
     new Date(2014, 10,  28, 21),
     new Date(2014, 10,  29, 22)]
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    enableInteractivity: false,
    hAxis: {
        window: 'explicit',
        viewWindow: {
          min: new Date(2014, 10, 14),
          max: new Date(2014, 10, 20)
      }
    },
            ticks: [new Date(2014, 10, 14), new Date(2014, 10, 15), new Date(2014, 10, 16)]
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Below is URL to edit above code online:
https://jsfiddle.net/t8Luy7qu/

I am trying to set minimum date as 14th Nov 2014 and maximum date as 20th Nov 2014 so graph should be horizontally scrollable for dates after 20th Nov(in current graph upto 28th Nov).

I have refereed following URL for achieve same functionality :
[set x Axis range in google chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341285/set-x-axis-range-in-google-chart)

and it works for numeric data on X-axis but I am using dates so can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this u want? https://jsfiddle.net/sivaprakashv/t8Luy7qu/9/

Comment: No Sivaprakash, I don't want to only enable scrollbar but want to set dates on X-axis such that there will be dates like(14th Nov, 15th Nov, 16th Nov, 17th Nov,...,20thNov) and data after 20th Nov shoulb be scrollable(upto 28th Nov in this case)

Comment: I think, [google.visualization.ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) will help you.

Comment: Google chart filter will trim data outside selected range, I want to show data outside specific range with scrollbar enabled

Comment: Is it possible to fulfill  above mentioned requirements for timeline chart in some other jQeury graph library?

Comment: Hi @ani , I'm very new to this google chart. You may google it for finding any other jQuery graph lib to meet your requirements.

Comment: Regarding setting the range, this post helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33902774/3165748